# Is arccos(-1/4) a rational number times pi?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In searching extremes of Chebyshev-functions of the second kind, I encountered the equation $\frac{\sin((k+1)\theta)}{\sin(k(\theta))}=\frac{k+1}{k}$. For $k=2$ one gets the polynomial equation $2z^2+z+2=0$ and the complex roots $z=-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{i\sqrt{15}}{4}$ and its conjugate. Since the roots have norm $1$, I wondered whether the argument $\theta$ of $z$ in polar form can be expressed as a rational fraction of $\pi$.

Comment: Please improve formatting by using $\LaTeX$/MathJax.

Answer (score 3):

If $\cos\theta=-\frac{1}{4}$ then $\theta\not\in\pi\mathbb{Q}$. Let $f(x)=2x^2-1$, $a_0=-\frac{1}{4}$ and $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$. The first terms of this sequence are
$$ a_0=-\frac{1}{4},\qquad a_1=-\frac{7}{8},\qquad a_2=\frac{17}{32},\qquad a_3=-\frac{223}{512} $$
and it is simple to check by induction that $\nu_2(a_n)$ is decreasing towards $-\infty$. In particular the sequence $\cos\theta,\cos(2\theta),\cos(4\theta),\cos(8\theta),\ldots$ is not periodic and $\theta$ cannot be a rational multiple of $\pi$.

---

As an alternative approach, $\cos\theta=-\frac{1}{4}$ and $\theta\in\pi\mathbb{Q}$ imply that $\frac{-1+\sqrt{-15}}{4}$ is a root of unity. $\frac{-1+\sqrt{-15}}{4}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, but it is not an algebraic *integer*, hence it cannot be a root of unity.

Comment: Thanks. I try to find the roots of the equation sin((k+1)θ)/sin(k(θ))=(k+1)/k.

Comment: I try to find the roots of the equation sin((k+1)θ)/sin(k(θ))=(k+1)/k, for k=2,3,..Put z=e^iθ. Then kz^(2k)-(k+1)z^(2k-1)+kz^(2k-2)-...-(k+1)z+k=0. z=1 is a double root.Can you advise me for literature on tne subject?

Comment: Very nice proof.
Yet I was wondering:
Why does it need to be an algebraic integer to be a root of unity?